# Como adicionar linha e colunas dinamicamente em um TableLayoutPanel C#?

Tags: c#, grid

Eu tenho um `TableLayoutPanel` exibido em forma de grid na tela que já possui uma quantidade X de linhas e colunas, além de conter também componentes em suas células.
Permito, por meio de uma tela, que o usuário altere a quantidade de linhas e colunas do `TableLayoutPanel` afim de disponibilizar novas células no grid para que o usuário arraste novos componentes à tela.
Encontrei soluções que me permitem criar o que quero, desde que já adicione um componente novo a linha ou coluna criada, caso que não desejo. O trecho de código abaixo mostra o tipo de situação que encontrei e não me serve:

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());

//para adicionar, neste caso, uma nova linha devo passar algum 
//componente para ser colocado na célula. Quero apenas criar uma
//célula vazio
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Componente(), coluna, novaLinha);
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Qual e o problema de fazer `this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Control(), coluna, novaLinha);`?

Comment: O problema é que a célula já vai ficar com um componente nela. Gostaria que a célula ficasse vazia, de modo que o usuário, a partir de uma lista, possa visualizar quais as células estão disponíveis para que ele possa criar o componente que quiser ali.

Comment: Sim isso entendi, mas se utilizar `new control()` a célula não fica *"como que vazia"*?

Comment: Visivelmente sim, porém existe uma lógica que opera sobre meu TableLayoutPanel, de modo que, existindo um componente ali outro não pode ser criado.

Comment: Não vejo outra forma de fazer isso, com `tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add()`, sem passar um *Control*. Em vez de `new control()` use `new control("Vazio");`. Na sua lógica verifique a propriedade `Text` do *Control* e se for "Vazio" permita que outro seja criado.